# Velocity properties file through web.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, velocity

I'm trying to use a ClasspathResourceLoader for loading my *.vm files. I have them in /WEB-INF/templates, which I've added to the build path. My web.xml has:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletVelocity</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.edw.servlet.VelocityServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.velocity.properties</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/velocity.properties</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

The velocity.properties file is placed in the WEB-INF folder. The key/values I need are:

```
resource.loader = class
class.resource.loader.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
```

However, when I try:

```
template = Velocity.getTemplate("index.vm");
```

I get:

```
Exception caught: Unable to find resource 'index.vm'
```

I've read that this could happen if my ResourceLoader failed, but I've specified it in the properties file to be the correct one, which works.

By default, Velocity uses a velocity.properties file located inside the jar. If I edit *that* one (the two aforementioned keys/values), everything works. My presumption would be that the velocity.properties mentioned in my web.xml fails to load, however I can see this in my console as I run the servlet:

```
INFO:  Velocity  [trace] Searching for properties at: /WEB-INF/velocity.properties
INFO:  Velocity  [debug] Configuring Velocity with properties at: /WEB-INF/velocity.properties
...
INFO:  Velocity  [debug] Initializing Velocity, Calling init()...
INFO:  Velocity  [debug] Default Properties File: org\apache\velocity\runtime\defaults\velocity.properties (???)
INFO:  Velocity  [debug] ResourceLoader instantiated: org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
INFO:  Velocity  [trace] ClasspathResourceLoader : initialization complete.
```

BUT, if I edit the default velocity.properties file inside the velocity jar (org\apache\velocity\runtime\defaults\velocity.properties), everything works just fine, I can load the .vm okay: no errors.

Comment: Please add your answer as "Answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files in **/WEB-INF/templates** are not in class path, I'm not sure about Velocity but Spring's ClassPathResourceLoader can't find files in that folder, you must use a web context resource loader then.

Comment: I have added the /WEB-INF/templates to the build path (classpath?), as the apache website says.

Answer (score 1):

When you call Velocity.doanything, you are asking the Velocity singleton to do it.  Your velocity properties are configuring the VelocityServlet, not the Velocity singleton.

Look at some of the example servlet apps in the VelocityTools project.  There you will find a superior servlet that is not deprecated and some examples of how Velocity is used in a servlet environment.